# jQuery live vertical news ticker...

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am pretty new to the world of jQuery & Ajax and I was hoping to get a bit of support/help from the community. Essentially I am trying to create a 'facebook-esqu' news board for a number of pre-determined news feeds.

I have a list element that dynamically create's a list on page load via Java (JSF2 to be exact) which is built from my db. What I would like is an ajax function (simple ajax poll would suffice) to check for a change, and where a change is applicable to perform a simple fade-out/fade-in function for the new list element. Whether this update list element is plonked on the bottom of the list (like a scroller animation)  or it remains in its place I dont mind I am just confused on how I can acheive this.

Here is a crude representation of my thinkings:

```
onPage load:
List Item 1
List Item 2
List Item 3 

OnAjax Update:
List Item 1
List Item 2 <--- Update Identified so fade element out
List Item 3

OnAjax After Update:
List Item 1
List Item 2a <--- Fade new element in
List Item 3
```

Hope someone can help.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the question is that you are asking us to write the code for you.  But, to give you a little push in the right direction:

Let's say that when you call the JSF2 page for updates, it is returning just the updated items, something like this:

```
{{id: 2, status: "removed"},
 {id: 2a, status: "added", text: "This is a new element"},
 {id: 4, status: "added", text: "This element 4"}}
```

You would then have a function that loops over the JSON results, looking through the status field.

If the representation was something like:

```
<div id="listelements">
   <div id="1">List Item 1</div>
   <div id="2">List item 2</div>
   <div id="3">List Item 3</div>
</div>
```

Then your code could look something like this:

```
for (each element in JSON string as element) {
  if (element.status == 'removed') { 
    $('#' + element.id).fadeOut().remove();
  } else if (element.status == 'added') {
    $("#listelements").append('<div id="' + element.id 
      + '" style="display:none;">' 
      + element.text + '</div>');
    $("#" + element.id).fadeIn();
  }
}
```

Please note that I haven't debugged this code, so I'm not sure if it's going to work 100%.  It's a nudge in one possible direction to get you started.  You'll find that after you've started to work on this, you'll get better answers if you ask more specific questions.